# I'm missing my left leg, What can I do for exercise?

Tags: exercise, cardio, disability

I need help, like 4 months ago. I can't seem to get out this hole I'm in. I cant move around really well. I have gained so much weight. I need advice.

Comment: Where are you at in terms of rehab? I think that's generally the first step in regaining mobility after amputation. If you have a prosthetic, but coordination is your main limitation, you could try a rowing machine and just keep your legs straight. (Generally, I think you're supposed to use your legs on rowing machines, but upper back only would be better than no exercise at all, I guess.

Comment: It may help users attempting to answer this question if they knew a bit about what you've been trying and what hasn't worked and even how you're feeling about it (a psychological answer could potentially be found in another SE)

Comment: Take a look at the Men's Health from a month or two ago. Their man of the year has one arm and one leg and is in amazing shape. (Combat veteran).

Answer (score 0):

These days you can do just about anything you want.  Adaptive equipment is available for most activities and [sports](http://www.disabledsportsusa.org/resources/adaptive-sports/).  Prosthetics have come a long way and your rehab team and [prosthetist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthetist) should be able to help you meet your goals.  The "[blade runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Pistorius)" ran in the Olympics.

When you think about it, everything we use is some type of adaptive equipment.  A car is designed to adapt to our bodies with the steering wheel for our hands and the pedals for our feet because that is how most of our bodies are arranged.  But if you don't have use of your legs, these days you can have all the controls at your hands.

The same goes for exercise and sports.  If you don't have a conventional body, someone has a non-conventional adaptation to help you achieve what you want to do.  Start with whatever it was that you liked to do before and have your rehab team get to work with you.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go talk to your physio, as they'll be able to give you some tailored suggestions, in addition to the usual balance / flexibility exercises. Anyway a few ideas you could discuss with them:

- Making it from one side of a hospital to the other. For places built for the sick and infirm most are very poorly designed, and a bit of an obstacle course, especially if in a chair or on crutches. So best to think of them as specifically designed obstacle course, intended to help patients regain condition, otherwise the frustration and the physical effort required to navigate their corridors may leave you in a tachycardic state. The number of magnetically locked fire doors that require you to press a wall mounted release button with one hand and pull the door open with another is amazing, till you realise they're only there to build and test your balance, coordination and upper body strength.
- Swimming, back stroke, assuming you can find a pool with suitable access, and initially some suitably trained life guards to natter to. They'll lose interest in you once you can do 1000m. Just make sure the pool has a very shallow end, or a lift, else getting out may be interesting, and amuse any kids in the vicinity.
- Walking, if only a few hundred yards a day to a post box or shop. Initially even this may leave you a sweating wreck.
- Modified Push ups / Planking, if only a few, as good for the back as well as the upper body.
- Sit ups, but be careful, you'll have lost a lot of conditioning, and your glutes will more than likely be rather flabby, so only a few or you'll end up with carpet burns.
- Pilates / Yoga, to stretch muscles you never knew you had.

On the weight front, start to keep a food diary, or probably easier to use an App such as MyFitnessPal. It should help you work out where the majority of your calories are coming from, and where you can cut down. Note as your activity levels will have probably been reduced to the Sedentary classification, so your daily calorie requirement may be a third lower than that of an active individual.